# Merge App Profile Page fans with Page fans (without being an admin)

Tags: facebook

One of the Pages I manage also has an App with the same name and its own followers/users. I'm not an admin of the App so I can't see the Merge prompt shown in [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/). But I am an admin of the official Page.

Is there a way I can manually request that the users of the App be merged into the brand's official Page?

Any help you can provide would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should be Administrator of both Application and Facebook page, and both need to have same name.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible without admin normally you can simply request the person to make you admin of app page than you can merge the both pages